# How to properly complete Completable inside flatMap chain?

Tags: android, rx-java, reactive-programming, rx-android, rx-java2

I have a task to connect to remote service. When it is not connected - fire up whole connecting procedure, if is already connected - just complete. For this purpose i wrote this method -

```
public Completable execute() {
        return fptrService.isConnected()
            .flatMap(isConnected -> {
                if (isConnected) return Single.never();
                else return bluetoothService.isBluetoothAvailable();
            })
            .flatMap(isAvailable -> {
                if (isAvailable) return bluetoothService.isBluetoothActivated();
                else throw new BluetoothNotAvailableException();
            })
            .flatMap(isActivated -> {
                if (isActivated) return bluetoothService.searchForFptr();
                else throw new BluetoothNotActivatedException();
            })
            .flatMapCompletable(fptrService::connect);
    }
```

In 1st case, when service is not connected - all works fine. But if on the first stage isConnected() returns TRUE all chain stalls and Completable not completes at all. What can i do to force complete on first stage?

Comment: try to return `Completable.complete()` instead of Single.never()

Comment: Tried...( But flatMap wants to return Single<Boolean>, not Completable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    .flatMap(isConnected -> {
        if (isConnected) return Single.never();
        else return bluetoothService.isBluetoothAvailable();
    })
```

What you have told by this, is that if `isConnected` is `true`, then never emit an item, thus this observable will never terminate.

Instead, you should pass downstream a `Single of false`:

```
    .flatMap(isConnected -> {
        if (isConnected) return Single.just(Boolean.FALSE);
        else return bluetoothService.isBluetoothAvailable();
    })
    // Will continue stream if `isConnected` is true
    .filter(isConnected -> isConnected)
    // if `isConnected` is false, then downstream operators won't be executed
```

Comment: This solution will cause BluetoothNotAvailableException on the second step of the chain, which may not the case. All i need is complete Completable at first step. I agree, that Single.never() just makes completable waiting forever... I think there is no "in chain" solution for this, i have to restructure queries...

Comment: @ЕвгенийКравцов, you cannot terminate the observable. You can `filter()` your observable for `isConnected` state, so after that operator you can be sure that exception won't be thrown. Updated the answer.